# How to set or modify the font size from a chart embedded in a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm programming an userform to show a graph with data stored in a range of cells, but when the graph shows it is so small and it gets impossible to read, and it shows another label with "series 2" even when i didn't added it.

I tried changing the properties of the image box, from "0 fmPictureSizeModeClip to fmPictureModeZoom but it only makes it blurry, i tried to modify my code adding:

```
MyChart.Parent.Width = 1200
MyChart.Parent.Height = 780
```

But it only the bars get big and the labels and title keeps small, and being unable to read.

```
Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered).Chart

   MyChart.Parent.Width = 1200
   MyChart.Parent.Height = 780
   MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ChartName
   MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ChartData
   MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("K32:K43")
```

This is the userform after adding:

```
     MyChart.Parent.Width = 1200
     MyChart.Parent.Height = 780
```

[image: img]

and this is before it, as you may see the text is illegible, the name of the chart in the screenshot disappeared but i corrected the code and now it appears but just as small as the other text in the chart

[image: img]

If complementary info needed i will gladly provide it,
any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe whatyou are looking for is `MyChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, where you suggest that i should put this code, or how i have to implement it? i just pasted into the code and i got an compilation error.

Comment: You'll need to give it a value -- ex `MyChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 10`. I also assumed you only needed series labels enlarged. Charts are kind of weird in VBA, you may want to try recording changes in the font sizes so see how to handle each one

Comment: when i compile the code it gives me a compilation error "1004" invalid parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

```
    MyChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 20
    MyChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Size = 20
    MyChart.Legend.Font.Size = 20
    MyChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size=24
```